# magento2: как заменить логотип в меню админ панели

Tags: php, magento

Подскажите как заменить логотип в меню(админ панель) magento2 не харкодно. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это картинка типа logo.gif - то заменить ее на нужную с таким же названием и такого же размера.
Если это иконка в CSS - прописать правило в CSS.